# Exception handling design from class libarary

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm looking for some program design guidance.

I have a class library that handles data in a database. I have a winforms app that is the presentation layer for the user to input and manage data. Say for example the user inputs some data and attempts to save it.  From the winforms app I do something like:

```
MyTool theTool = new MyTool();
MyTool.FirstName = this.Textbox1.Text;
MyTool.LastName = this.Textbox2.Text;
//etc...
int result = MyTool.SaveData(); //result is the ID of the inserted record.
```

MyTool is a type in my class library.  Within this type I would have:

```
public int SaveData()
{
   if (IsReadyForInput())
   {
   //..open a DB connection and save out the data
   //..get the ID of the saved record
   }
   else
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("One or more arguments prevented saving the data");
   }
   return theID
}

private bool IsReadyForInput()
{
   if (this.FirstName.Length == 0)
   { return false; }
   if (this.LastName.Length == 0)
   {return false;}
   return true;
}
```

Now, what I'm interested in is the best design on how exception handling should work.  For example the above method is not specific at all so the user doesn't know what's wrong.  So I could rewrite this to do something like:

```
public void SaveData()
{
   string errMess = IsReadyForInput();
   if (errMess.Length == 0)
   {
      //..open a DB connection and save out the data
      //..get the ID of the saved record
   }
   else {
      throw new ArgumentException(errMess);
   }
   return theID
}

private string IsReadyForInput()
{
   if (this.FirstName.Length == 0)
   { return "Specify a first name"; }
   if (this.LastName.Length == 0)
   {return "Specify a last name";}
   return true;
}
```

However it just doesn't seem a very elegant (or fast) method to be comparing string lengths to find an error message.  I had tried writing something like:

```
public void SaveData()
{
   ValidateInput();
   //..open a DB connection and save out the data
   return theID
}

private void ValidateInput()
{
   if (this.FirstName.Length == 0)
   { throw new ArgumentException("Specify a first name"; }
   if (this.LastName.Length == 0)
   {throw new ArgumentException("Specify a first name"; }
}
```

The problem with this is that the exception is actually thrown by ValidateInput when the front end is calling "SaveData", so when the exception reaches the top, to me, it would seem less clear (especially if there are multiple ways of calling "ValidateInput()" from within MyTool).

Additionally I am not sure what the best way to handle the exception on the front end would be because, if an error is thrown, the ID is never returned.

I guess I am just looking for some guidance on how to handle this situation and validation/error handling in general.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I wonder about is whether you need to throw an exception at all when ordinary control flow might be enough:

```
if (IsReadyForInput())
{
    //..open a DB connection and save out the data
    //..get the ID of the saved record
}
else 
{
    //..do whatever you need in case of invalid input
}
```

The obvious problem with this suggestion is that we are in a method somewhere in your class library, and some of the desired effects (displaying warnings to the user, etc.) happen in the WinForms layer. That, however, suggests a better solution; namely, to do the validation in the WinForms code:

```
if (IsReadyForInput())
{
    int result = theTool.SaveData();
    //...and whatever else should happen.
}
else
{
    //..do whatever you need in case of invalid input
}
```

The above approach is simpler and makes the parts of your program less dependent on each other (as `MyTool` doesn't need to care about validation of user input) when compared to, e.g., throwing an exception or using special return values to signal failure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FluentValidation (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). I think it's what you're looking for.

With it you can define your validation rules and call its validation methods. It will return a full list of potential validation errors without causing exceptions to be thrown in your code.

Comment: Many thanks but I'm hoping to get some guidance on best practices and how others handle this so I can do it myself.  This would seem to be a very common structure for data entry...

Comment: The fluentvalidation does appear pretty kick ass though.

Comment: =) It's a good framework and many of the validation frameworks/patterns you will come across will be very similar.